# Use one ssh public key for multiple remote users

Tags: ssh, terminal, console, authorized-keys

I have my one local public key and I am trying to add it to two authorized_keys on a remote server for two different users (ex. users remote1 and remote1). I am able to ssh just fine as remote1; however, when I try to ssh as remote2, I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

I've checked that the file permissions are correct, and that the sshd_config is correct. Is there something I am missing? Am I not allowed to use the same public key across two different users' authorized_keys?

Here is the output of the failed ssh with -vvv:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /~/.ssh/config
debug1: /~/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /~/.ssh/config line 42: Applying options for myserver.remote2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserver.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /~/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to myserver.com:22 as 'remote2'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/~/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /~/.ssh/known_hosts:57
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from myserver.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DyCW5NZRG60MnXzQcgQmj2NQy0tH1BQwSrB7C98NdVE
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/~/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /~/.ssh/known_hosts:57
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from myserver.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/~/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /~/.ssh/known_hosts:56
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from X.X.X.X
debug1: Host 'myserver.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /~/.ssh/known_hosts:57
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /~/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:00000000000000000000000000000000000000000 agent
debug1: Will attempt key:  RSA SHA256:00000000000000000000000000000000000000001 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /~/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /~/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /~/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /~/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /~/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:00000000000000000000000000000000000000000 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key:  RSA SHA256:00000000000000000000000000000000000000001 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /~/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /~/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /~/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /~/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /~/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /~/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /~/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
remote2@myserver.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've double checked to make sure my public key is in the authorized_keys file for the remote2 user and that the permissions on the file are correct but I'm still getting a type 51 response on my public key.

Comment: One of the first steps to figuring out ssh problems is to turn up the verbosity level all the way (`-vvv`) on the ssh client and sshd daemon, make a connection attempt, and look at the verbose output. Can you gather those and edit your question to include them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not asking the right question.

The public key can be used on multiple servers, your problem is probably somewhere else. remote2 cannot know whether or not the public key is used on another server.

The output of your -vvv is the same as if you had tried to connect to the server without adding your public key beforehand.

You can try to remove it and add it again.
You can add the public key with the `ssh-copy-id` command to be more safe.

Sorry this is all the help I can give with the current information.